# How do I block websites for several PCs via wireless router?

Tags: wireless, websites

Our household has 3 PC/laptops connected via wireless router (d-link 600). Is there a way to ban websites to all of the PCs connected to the wireless router by using my laptop? D-link's filter website feature is not working.

Comment: Please provide a bit more information. If your Laptop is running Ubuntu and your laptop is running all day you could install a proxy (e.g. squid). Than you have to configure all other computers to use your laptop as proxy to access the internet and you have to block all other PCs in your router to avoid bypassing the proxy

Answer (score 3):

Use [OpenDNS](http://www.opendns.com/home-solutions/) to filter everything you like. Register a free account and follow their instructions.

Answer (score 2):

Try [web filter](http://www.aobo-porn-filter.com/), you can block unwanted sites by URL or keywords.

Answer (score 0):

You can use alternative [Openwrt](https://openwrt.org) firmware for the [Dlink DIR 600](https://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/d-link/dir-600) and use [dnsmasq](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131617/how-can-i-block-a-subdomain-with-dnsmasq)
with PREROUTING IPTABLES rules:

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 53 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 53
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p udp --dport 53 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 53
```

your `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` should look like:

```
address=/blockeddomain.com/127.0.0.1
address=/blockeddomain2.com/127.0.0.1
```

For more information see help on [dnsmasq](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/dhcp.dnsmasq).